# error 1054 MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Estoy usando postman y quiero hacer un delete por id pero me tira error 1054, aunque yo utilizo [req.params.id]. A continuación muestro el error y mi query, se agradece ayuda!:

```
{
    "code": "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR",
    "errno": 1054,
    "sqlMessage": "Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'",
    "sqlState": "42S22",
    "index": 0,
    "sql": "DELETE FROM tasks  WHERE id='15'"
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////

```
 routes.delete('/:id', (req,res)=>{
   
    req.getConnection((err, conn)=>{
      
        if(err) return res.send(err)
 
        conn.query("DELETE FROM tasks  WHERE id= ?",[req.params.id] , (err, rows)=>{
            
         if(err) return res.send(err)
         
 
        res.send("La tarea ha sido eliminada")
        })
    })
 })
```

Comment: cual es la estructura de tu tabla ??

Comment: Si te refieres a mi tabla en la db, es: tasks_id (primary key), task_title, task_description. Si te referis a otra tabla decime que por ahi no entendi! graciaaaas

Comment: Y si la columna es `tasks_id` entonces por que quieres actualizar la `id` ??

Comment: Quiero eliminar por id, entonces estoy nombrando mal  el parametro o lo estoy llamando mal en la query?

Comment: Si tu columna se llama task_id, lo que quieres buscar es task_id. La columna de nombre "id" no existe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la estructura de tu tabla `task` es:

```
tasks_id (primary key) | task_title | task_description
```

Tu consulta debiese ser, para el DELETE:

```
DELETE FROM tasks WHERE task_id = '15'
```

Actualmente estás buscando una columna que no existe, por eso es que el error menciona:

> Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'

O sea: Columna 'id' desconocida en clausula WHERE.